# Max,Min,Range,Std Dev Brightness Temperture from Landsat in Arc Gis or any Software

Tags: max, arcgis, min, temperature, landsat

I have a Landsat image, I derive Brightness, Temperature but I need to extract Min, Max, Range and Std Dev for this image. However, each of these values must be extracted from an image.

For example, to minimum brightness temperature obtained a separate image and the remaining amounts are to be achieved as a separate images. Can anybody help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Arcigs, the Min,Max,Range and Std Dev will be computed with Summary Statistics and that is in the Analysis toolbox. 
To select a value, or a range of values, from the raster file. You would need to open the attribute table by right clicking on the raster file in the table of contents/layers. Click on Table options on the top left corner. Then select "Select by attributes." Then select the column name that has the values that you wish to select from. Double click on the that name. That will load the column name in the box on the bottom. Then use the greater, greater equal, lesser, or lesser equal options and that will be added to the box. Then add the value that you want. Hit okay. Back on the attributes table on the bottom there is an option to highlight the selected value. Hit that, then close the attribute table. Back on the map now should have all the raster points that have been selected based on the query. From this point, you need to right click on the raster file once again and find Selection. Select "Create New Layer" option. Now you have the original raster file and now a new one based on your query.